# Disabled textbox/textarea still active

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a multi-line textBox disabled through vb.net :

```
myTxtA.enabled= false
```

The html it outputs :

```
<textarea name="myTxtA" rows="10" id="myTxtA" disabled="disabled" style="width:99%;">
...
</textarea>
```

That's the source code I get through the browser but the textArea is still editable in the browser. There is no javascript modifying myTxtA, and the only other reference to myTxtA in my codeFile is the following :

```
If somethingNotHappeningHere Then
   myTxtA.ReadOnly = True
End If
```

I can't see why my textarea is still editable. Can the class of the div containing the textArea modify its behaviour ?

PS: I am not concerned about if the data is sent or not. I'm just looking for the textArea to be uneditable.

**Edit:** Same problem on IE7 and Firefox 3.5

**Edit 2:** When I copy all the html source from my browser into a new html file the textarea is properly disabled...

Comment: Which browser are you using? (because when I view a page containing that html (plus a closing tag) in both IE8 and FF 3, the text area is disabled)

Comment: have you checked output in other browsers too?

Comment: Edited the question: Same problem on IE7 and Firefox 3.5

Comment: Could you post you aspx-code and your (complete) vb-code? I think the problem is somewhere 'around' you Textbox/area, because here my Textboxes are behaving normally.

Comment: I prefer not to post the code and the pages are quite big but I'll try and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
If  !IsPostBack
```

[Read about How psotback works in ASP.NET](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18)

Comment: I can't see how the PostBack would affect in my case. On what should I add an If Not IsPostBack condition ?

Answer (score 0):

TextArea? Is this an external component? Or just an html-Textarea? Try using a TextBox, with `TextMode` set to `MultiLine`. This wil render a TextArea and you can Enable/Disable this control by setting the `Enabled`-property to `true`/`false`.

Comment: In my aspx code I have <ASP:TEXTBOX [...] textmode="MultiLine"... which apparently outputs a <textarea...

Comment: Ah, now I see! I must have read over "The html it outputs". sorry! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your docType at the top of your aspx/html page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?:

```
<textarea readonly="true"></textarea>
```

I find it to be a little more versatile since you have the scrollbar active if your textarea data goes beyond the rows displayed, and I find it to be less finicky than disable.

I know this is old, but putting it here for future SO'ers